# Variable 'this.userInfo' is unbound and cannot be determined

Tags: spring, maven, jdo, pojo

I am developing a maven JDO project, but I am getting this error when I am trying to make relation between two tables (user_login, user_role)

User_Login: user_id(primary key), user_name, user_password,user_role_id

User_Role: id(primary key), role

**user_role_id is same as id of user_role table**

User.java:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "user_login")
public class User {  
@PrimaryKey
@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer userId=0;
@Column(name="user_profile_name")
private String userProfileName=null; 
@Column(name="user_email")
private String userEmail=null;
@Column(name="user_contact")
private String userContact=null;
@Column(name="user_name")
private String userName=null;
@Column(name="user_password")
private String userPassword=null;
@ManyToOne
@Column(name="user_role_id")   
private Integer userRoleId=0;
```

Role.java:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "user_role")
public class Role {
@PrimaryKey
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id=0;
@Column(name="role")
private String role=null;   

@OneToMany
private User userInfo=null;
```

DAOImpol:

```
public List<Role> getUser(String username, String userpassword) {
    PersistenceManager pm = this.pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    JDOPersistenceManager jdopm = (JDOPersistenceManager)pm;       
    try {
    // Start the transaction
    tx.begin(); 

    TypesafeQuery<User> tq = jdopm.newTypesafeQuery(User.class);
    //QUser user = QUser.candidate();
    QRole role = QRole.candidate();
    QUser userInfo=role.userInfo;
    List<Role> result = tq.filter(userInfo.userName.eq(username).and(userInfo.userPassword.eq(userpassword))).executeList();

    //result = tq.executeResultList(true, user.userId);

    if(result.size()>0){
        log.info(">>>>>00000000"+"    "+result.get(0).getUser().getUserEmail());
        log.info(">>>>>11111111"+"    "+result.get(0).getRoleId()+"    "+result.get(0).getRole());
    }else{
        log.info("<<<<<<<=====000000");
    }
    // Commit the transaction, flushing the object to the datastore
    tx.commit();
    return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            // Error occurred so rollback the transaction
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Variable 'this.userInfo' is unbound and 
cannot be determined (is it a misspelled field name? or is not intended
to be a variable?)
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Variable 
'this.userInfo' is unbound and cannot be determined (is it a   
misspelled   
field name? or is not intended to be a variable?)
```

Comment: I do not really know JDO, but it looks like you forgot to say it how to process `Role.userInfo`. Should'nt you add attributes to `OneToMany` annotation ?

Comment: You're putting JPA annotations in a JDO project. This is totally wrong and I told you this in a previous question of yours; evidently ignored. Also a relation is not an "Integer". Have you read any JDO docs?

Comment: @Neil...i got very few resources. so its difficult for me. I want to map this 2 table. can u tell me some usful llinks?

Comment: You're using DataNucleus JDO, yes? so why not start from their website and documentation? http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/products/accessplatform.html

Comment: i want to use Querydsl JDO. ANd i think my persistent declaration is not correct. i am opening another question. Can u pls check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890952/persistence-declaration-in-spring
can u pls check this @Neil

Answer (score 0):

I found that you'll get this error from JDO if you're using progaurd and progaurd renames your private fields.  Adding a -keep to the progaurd config to keep the package with your Persistence Capable classes will fix it.

For example, if you keep all of your Persistence Capable classes in com.example.server.orm package you'd add this to progaurd.conf

```
-keep class com.example.server.orm.** {*;}
```